# Shiny R, Using the downloadButton function

Tags: r, download, shiny

I'm trying to figure out how to use a downloadButton to download multiple content to one pdf file. I have in the ui the download button created:

```
downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download Data'))
```

and I am trying to get multiple plots and tables into one pdf file. I have in the server file the following

```
 output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('data-', Sys.Date(), '.pdf', sep=&rdquo;)
    }
```

but I think this will save multiple csv files. How do i download multiple plots and tables from renders such as

```
output$table<-renderTable({
        P.Value<- c(lev.p,bart.p,turn.p,shap.p,jar.p,linm.p) 
        Test.Statistic<-c(lev.s,bart.s,turn.s,shap.s,jar.s,linm.s) 
        df<-data.frame(P.Value,Test.Statistic)
        rownames(df, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "row")
        rownames(df) <- c("Levene Test","Bartlett Test","Turning Point Test","Shapiro-Wilk Test","Jarque Bera Test","Linear Model Constant Drift Test")

        df
  })
```

,

```
  output$qq.line<-renderPlot({

    index<-1:length(lg.ret.vec())
    model<-lm((lg.ret.vec())~ index) 
    plot(model,which=2,main="QQ plot of the residuals",xlab="Theoretical Quantiles")             
    qqline(rstandard(model),col="black")
  })
```

,

```
  output$histogram<-renderPlot({

      hist(lg.ret(),main="Histogram of log returns",xlab="Log returns")
  })
```

to name just a few.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of `rmarkdown` to make a report with all your plots, [here is one example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html).

In your case you could use the following `downloadHandler` (code adapted from the link):

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('report', sep = '.','html')
    },

    content = function(file) {
      src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')

      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd')

      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('report.Rmd',html_document())
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )
```

And create a file called `report.Rmd` in the same folder as your server.R and ui.R:

**report.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Your report"
output: html_document
---

This is your plot

```{r echo=FALSE}
    index<-1:length(lg.ret.vec())
    model<-lm((lg.ret.vec())~ index) 
    plot(model,which=2,main="QQ plot of the residuals",xlab="Theoretical Quantiles")             
    qqline(rstandard(model),col="black")

```

This is your histogram

```{r echo=FALSE}
hist(lg.ret(),main="Histogram of log returns",xlab="Log returns")
```
````

Comment: I've tried this and attempted to fiddle around with it but it just creates a html document with just a heading titled "report".

Comment: ok, you have the libraries installed?, also when I tried it I had to restart R everytime I changed the `report.Rmd` file, maybe it's cached

Comment: For all my plots it works, but for the example of the table stated in the question it doesn't. P.Value and test.statistic are just vectors of numeric values. Do you have any idea why it isn't working for the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

you need to define content to download for downloadHandler. see http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/shiny/docs/downloadHandler

How do you mean you are trying to download plots and tables to a single csv file?  Do you mean to merge the data?  You may be confused about what a csv file is.

Comment: I understand how to define content, but its just trying to define multiple content to put in one file. My mistake on the csv part, I meant any well known file that can display the table, plots and results (such as .pdf or .xls),

Comment: maybe try define your content and use c()

    ...downloadHandler(filename, content = c(data1, data2, data3))

Comment: you said you think your supplied code downloads multiple ... files.  what actually happens when you run this?

Comment: I attempted to do it by using   output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$symb, 'from', input$dates[1], 'to', input$dates[2], '.pdf', sep="")
    },
    content = c(histogram,qq.line)
  ) but it says histogram and qq.line are not objects. When i ran the code before it didn't save multiple files (just gave errors), i just assumed it would save multiple files